# ¿Qué es lo opuesto de adicción?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos, antónimos

Según la RAE, la palabra *[adicción](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0k8i4DT)* se define como:

> Del lat. *addictio, -ōnis* 'adjudicación por sentencia'; *cf. adicto*.
>
> 1. f. Dependencia de sustancias o actividades nocivas para la salud o el equilibrio psíquico.
> 2. f. Afición extrema a alguien o algo.

¿Cuál sería su antónimo u opuesto?

No estoy realmente seguro que *[sobriedad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YB3hW6y)* lo sea.

Comment: Yo diría aversión.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para referirse a una actividad o acción opuesta a lo adictivo, recomiendo usar "templanza", "templado". Esta palabra aborda bien lo expuesto por Diego sobre los elementos claves de la palabra adicción: dependencia, extremo.

> **[Templanza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZQm69KL)**
>
> Del lat. *temperantia*.
>
> 1. f. **Moderación, sobriedad y continencia.**
> 2. f. Benignidad del aire o clima de un país.
> 3. f. *Pint.* Armonía y buena disposición de los colores.
> 4. f. *Rel*. Una de las cuatro virtudes cardinales, que consiste en moderar los apetitos y el uso excesivo de los sentidos, sujetándolos a
>      la razón.
> 5. f. desus. temple (‖ punto de dureza o elasticidad).

Comment: No creo que sea opuesto. Es no tomar demasiado como para ser dependiente de la bebida, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 6):

Creo que los dos significados tienen antónimos diferentes. Tratémoslos por separado.

> Dependencia de sustancias o actividades nocivas para la salud o el equilibrio psíquico.

Lo contrario de la dependencia es la independencia. Cuando no eres dependiente de algo, ese algo te resulta **[indiferente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LOJb0zM)** (que no despierta interés o afecto), que sería mi antónimo propuesto para este caso.

> Afición extrema a alguien o algo.

Me siento tentado a usar también aquí el antónimo *indiferente*, pero creo que en este caso lo contrario de algo que te causa una afición extrema es algo que te causa un extremo rechazo. La propuesta de ***[aversión](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4YtTXec)*** no me parece nada mal (rechazo o repugnancia frente a alguien o algo). Aunque una mejor podría ser ***[fobia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I8eNBy2)*** (aversión exagerada a alguien o algo).

Ejemplo: a mí el tabaco me causa indiferencia (no me siento tentado a fumar) y le tengo fobia (cuando fuman a mi lado).

Answer (score 6):

Yo diría que los elementos "clave" o definitorios de `adicción` son `dependencia` y `extrema`, según las definiciones que aportas.

Lo contrario a esta necesidad o dependencia extrema sería `autocontrol` o `uso moderado`. Es decir, lo contrario no es que no uses las sustancias o no tengas ciertas aficiones (como el WhatsApp o jugar al Wold of Warcraft), sino que te controles o moderes en su uso.

Depende mucho de cómo quieras aplicar este "antónimo" de dependencia. Sería como el que sólo fuma cuando sale o "solo se mete una raya de coca muy de vez en cuando". O como el que dice "A las 3 dejo la consola y me pongo a estudiar" y efectivamente a las 3:00, no importa cómo vaya la partida, lo deja y cambia de actividad como se había propuesto.

El antónimo es de hecho una **no dependencia** (que no independencia) de la sustancia o hábito, pero la mejor manera de explicarlo que a mí se me ocurre es refiriéndose al "autocontrol" o "uso moderado", ya que nadie dice que no tiene una "no dependencia" a algo, sino más bien que "no lo usan mucho", o "pueden parar cuando quieran", o "saben cuándo parar" o "no están enganchados", etc.

Answer (score 5):

No creo que exista un antónimo realmente adecuado para adicción.

Lo contrario de tener una adicción es no tenerla.
Es un concepto bastante extremo en ese sentido: hay distintos tipos de adicción, se puede tener adicción a muchas cosas diferentes, incluso en varios niveles, pero o la tienes o no.
Darle más vueltas es buscarle tres pies al gato.

Por tanto, lo que debes buscar es una palabra que signifique "*no tener una adicción*"... yo no conozco ninguna y tampoco es que haga falta, simplemente se niega y listo, que es lo que se hace normalmente, negarlo.

Comment: Claro, es está sano. Tener una vida sin drogas. Pero estoy de acuerdo. No hay palabra para eso. Solo descripciones.

Answer (score -2):

El antónimo de *adicción* sería algo más cercano a `conexión`, ya que no se es adicto solo a las drogas: eso es algo como un estereotipo del término.

Se puede ser adicto a cualquier cosa que sientas que dependes de tal, ya que mayormente un adicto está desconectado de lo que lo rodea, ya no teniendo nada que hacer, como estar sin amigos, no salir de casa, o no tener metas, solo siente que no tendría nada más que hacer si no tiene aquello a lo que siente dependencia el caso podría ser tal como la pornografía, los videojuegos, las redes sociales, el alcohol, las drogas, etc.

No tener algún *hobby* o algún otro pasatiempo hace que solo podamos hacer "eso", ya que nos sentimos condenados a no poder hacer nada más. Por eso no solo adicción se refiere a las drogas, siendo las drogas el causante de síntomas físicos más reconocibles no elimina las otras maneras a las que podríamos estar adictos a otras cosas.

Siendo la respuesta de resolver una adicción, la conexión con el mundo que te rodea, despertar todos los días con una meta, salir con amigos, leer un libro, hacer algo que te guste, etc.

La única forma de ayudar a un adicto no es repeliéndole de ti, sino conectándolo más con el mundo que lo rodea. :)

Comment: A mi no me parece que "conexión" sea el mejor término para definir la no necesidad o no dependencia de algo.