# ¿Es "castidad" lo opuesto a "lujuria"?

Tags: definiciones, sustantivos, antónimos

Haciendo limpieza en la casa de mis suegros ha aparecido un viejo ejemplar del Trivio 1000, uno de los muchos [juegos que Falomir editó en los 80 como plagios](http://retromemories.net/lo-10-mejores-juegos-de-mesa-que-plagio-falomir-juegos-1a-parte/) de otros juegos más famosos. He rescatado las tarjetas de preguntas porque prometen ser una mina. Aquí va una pregunta de una de ellas:

> ¿Qué es lo opuesto a la lujuria?
>   **La castidad.**

Sin embargo, según el diccionario tenemos:

> **[lujuria](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NgoG0zM)**
>
> Del lat. *luxuria*.
>
> 1. f. Deseo excesivo del placer sexual.

Mientras que:

> **[castidad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7qyewB6)**
>
> Del lat. *castĭtas, -ātis*.
>
> 2. f. Virtud de quien se abstiene de todo goce carnal.

Vemos que la lujuria es un deseo, algo que se siente, mientras que la castidad es una virtud, algo que se practica. Uno puede sentir lujuria y practicar la castidad, no veo que sean excluyentes y, por tanto, opuestos. Yo consideraría la inapetencia como antónimo de lujuria, tal vez.

¿Qué pensáis? ¿Se puede romper de algún modo una lanza a favor de Falomir? ¿O consideráis la respuesta como errónea?

Comment: Podría ser que lo opuesto a casto sea fornicario?

Comment: Un antónimo de lujuria; «recato».

Answer (score 11):

Para el cristianismo existen los llamados "siete [pecados capitales](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pecados_capitales)" (lujuria, gula, avaricia, pereza, ira, envidia, soberbia), y a éstos les corresponden [siete virtudes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siete_virtudes_(catecismo)) reconocidas por el catecismo. La virtud opuesta a la lujuria es precisamente la castidad.

El juego, evidentemente, no está usando las definiciones del diccionario, sino las del catecismo.

Comment: En ese caso, ¿está la pregunta mal planteada? ¿Se debería haber preguntado cuál es la virtud opuesta, y no simplemente "lo opuesto"?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Siendo Falomir una empresa española, y dado el tradicional clericalismo español, ¿puede ser que se haya dado por hecho que el usuario del juego conocería esa oposición pecado-virtud más de lo que conocía el significado exacto de cada palabra?

Comment: Uno de los temas de las preguntas de uno de estos plagios del Trivial Pursuit era la religión; no sé si es este u otro. No sé si sería este juego u otro parecido.

Comment: Curioso que según el primer enlace la tristeza fue en algún momento un pecado capital.

Answer (score 7):

Creo que la respuesta puede darse en dos sentidos:

- Puesto en su **contexto histórico**, se puede decir que **no hay error**.
- Mirado desde el **presente**, hay que admitir que la pregunta **puede verse ambigua**.

Analicemos cada uno por separado, partiendo por el presente:

---

**1. Basados en el castellano actual, ¿es la castidad lo opuesto a la lujuria?**

—Veamos:

La primera acepción de **castidad** (que quizá omites porque parece circular) dice:

> 1. f. Cualidad de casto.

a su vez, la primera acepción define [*casto*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7rOnAo2) como:

> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que se abstiene de todo goce sexual, **o se atiene a lo que se considera como lícito.** *[énfasis añadido]*
> 2. adj. Que no posee en sí sensualidad. Casto amor, deleite.

en ese sentido, también un casado es casto siendo fiel a su mujer, aunque no se *abstenga de todo goce sexual* con ella.

Respecto a la palabra **lujuria**, efectivamente la entrada de la 23ª edición del DLE mirada aisladamente parece excluir la práctica, pero hay antecedentes de que puede no ser tan así:

- Tanto la [22ª edicion del DLE (2001)](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=I1g7iyigHDXX2eCKWsel) como el [*Diccionario Esencial* (2006)](http://lema.rae.es/desen/?key=lujuria) definen lujuria en primer lugar como ***Vicio*** consistente en el **uso** ilícito o en el apetito **desordenado** de los deleites carnales [énfasis añadidos].
- La misma 23ª edición define [lujurioso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ngu6s9o) como:

  > Dado o entregado a la lujuria

  donde *[dado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BrtRK35)* y *[entregado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FltFypa)* vienen de formas pronominales y las respectivas acepciones implican ceder y declararse vencido (en este caso, frente al deseo).
- Por otro lado, la misma palabra *deseo* tiene entre sus acepciones *[impulso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=L9MJRDS), excitación venérea*. Ambos sustantivos admiten un grado de acción en este contexto.

Ignoro las razones de la RAE para dar a la entrada su forma actual, pero **poniendo las cosas en contexto, no se puede decir que la oposición castidad-lujuria sea errónea, aunque sí que admite ambigüedad**. Pero vamos, que también la oposición claro-oscuro puede ser ambigua porque claro también es antónimo de turbio.

---

**2. En el contexto en que fue creado el juego, ¿es más o menos correcto que sea la castidad lo opuesto a la lujuria?**

Parafraseando a [Massimo d'Azeglio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massimo_d%27Azeglio), juzgar un juego de una época según el diccionario de otra es el más injusto de los sistemas ([él lo decía de personas](https://books.google.cl/books?id=JmXphV8ELtUC&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q=giudicare%20uomo%20eta%20secondo%20le%20idee%20altra%20fallace%20ed%20ingiusto%20dei%20sistemi&f=false) e ideas, por cierto).

Mirado desde los ochenta, la principal dificultad (la acepción de lujuria en la 23ª edición) simplemente desaparece.

Por otro lado, engarzo con la respuesta de pablodf76 para decir que en los años ochenta la relación del español medio con el catolicismo era distinta a la de hoy. No encontré datos de la época, pero sólo unos pocos años antes —según un [estudio de la Biblioteca del Congreso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_Spain#Democratic_Spain) de EE.UU.—, un 95% de españoles era bautizado (hoy ronda el 70% según [RTVE](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/videos/telediario/catolicismo-diferencia-confesion-mas-numerosa-espana/1718843/) y [El País](https://elpais.com/diario/2011/08/07/sociedad/1312668002_850215.html#despiece2?rel=mas)) y 60% iba a misa y el 30% lo hacía regularmente (hoy es aproximadamente [un tercio](http://www.lavanguardia.com/vangdata/20150402/54429637154/interactivo-creencias-y-practicas-religiosas-en-espana.html) de eso). Además, según cuentan, el anticlericalismo era mucho menos marcado en esa época.

A consecuencia de lo anterior, **resulta razonable pensar que en los ochenta la pregunta diera mucho menos lugar a dudas**.

Por supuesto, ni soy historiador, ni vivo en España, ni supe leer hasta bien avanzada la década de los 80, de modo que si queda alguna duda sugiero zanjar este punto preguntando a un español de 60 años o más.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, en mi opinión. Incluso para fechas recientes es importante a veces el contexto histórico.

Comment: Omití la primera acepción de "castidad" porque simplemente redirigía a "casto", y la primera acepción de "casto" me parecía similar a la ya expuesta para "castidad", mientras que la segunda me parecía irrelevante para la pregunta. Una excelente respuesta.

Comment: Gran respuesta, Rafael. Tu uso de _los '80_ me hizo investigar sobre ello y lo planteé en [¿Es correcto usar '80 o 80s para referirnos a décadas?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21801/1674). Lo correcto sería _los ochenta_. Por cierto, me pareció muy inspiradora la cita de Massiom d'Azeglio.

Answer (score 2):

Tomando como referencia, la [respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19762/14481) de Pablo Baeza, considero que lo opuesto de lujuría sería Templanza en su cuarta acepción:

> **[Templanza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZQm69KL)**
>
> Del lat. *temperantia*.
>
> 1. f. Moderación, sobriedad y continencia.
> 2. f. Benignidad del aire o clima de un país.
> 3. f. *Pint.* Armonía y buena disposición de los colores.
> 4. f. *Rel*. **Una de las cuatro virtudes cardinales, que consiste en moderar los apetitos y el uso excesivo de los sentidos, sujetándolos a
>      la razón.**
> 5. f. desus. temple (‖ punto de dureza o elasticidad).

De igual forma, la templanza bajo el punto de vista del [Cristianismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Templanza) indica que:

> «la templanza es la virtud moral que modera la atracción de los placeres y procura el equilibrio en el uso de los bienes creados. Asegura el dominio de la voluntad sobre los instintos y mantiene los deseos en los límites de la honestidad. La persona moderada orienta hacia el bien sus apetitos sensibles, guarda una sana discreción y no se deja arrastrar para seguir la pasión de su corazón»

Si lo vemos desde un punto de vista [filosófico](https://www.acfilosofia.org/materialesmn/filosofia-y-ciudadania-3013/filosofia-moral-y-politica-democracia-ciudadania/640-las-virtudes-cardinales), según Platón:

> La templanza es la virtud que modera las pasiones concupiscibles, principalmente las del tacto. En cuanto justo medio entre dos extremos no sólo se opone a intemperancia sino a insensibilidad. Su importancia reside en el hecho de que las virtudes forman en el  “êthos” un todo coherente, influyendo unas sobre otras. Por eso mi “deseo destemplado” disminuye seguramente el “sentido de la realdad” que es la prudencia, implica evidentemente una falta de fortaleza y conculca fácilmente la justicia. Ejemplo típico: el adulterio.

Considero que en escencia, ambos puntos de vista se refieren a lo mismo, detonando una moderación del instintos carnales y llevando a un estado de continencia.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que incluso usando las definiciones de hoy en día del DLE se podría decir que "castidad" si es lo opuesto a "lujuria". Veamos la otra acepción de castidad:

> [**castidad**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7qyewB6)
>
> Del lat. *castĭtas*, -*ātis*.
>
> 1. f. Cualidad de casto.
> 2. f. Virtud de quien se abstiene de todo goce carnal.

Como vemos, la primera acepción menciona la palabra "casto". Veamos su definición:

> [***casto, ta***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7rOnAo2)
>
> Del *lat. castus.*
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que se abstiene de todo goce sexual, o se atiene a lo que se considera como lícito.
> 2. adj. Que no posee en sí sensualidad. Casto amor, deleite.

En la segunda acepción vemos que casto es quién "no posee en sí sensualidad". Y para sensualidad:

> [**sensualidad**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xaa3Sc6)
>
> Del lat. tardío *sensualĭtas*, -*ātis*.
>
> 1. f. Cualidad de sensual.
> 2. f. Propensión excesiva a los placeres de los sentidos.

Con esto pienso que se podría reformular una definición de castidad y decir que se aplica a aquella persona que no posee en sí una inclinación excesiva al placer. O sea, no solamente abstenerse deliberadamente del deseo también el hecho de sentir muy poco deseo.

Answer (score 0):

Si de sentimientos se quiere hablar, yo creo que va mejor

> **Pudor**
>
> Sentimiento que lleva a ocultar lo que no se quiere que se vea,
>   especialmente en materias sexuales.
>
> *Ejemplo: Siete de cada diez guipuzcoanos aquejados de disfunción eréctil siguen sin acudir a la consulta médica por pudor.